Is there a working solution for background BLE Bluetooth fetching on iOS devices?
My app's main functionality is to scan for BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) devices in the background. I am using this flutter_blue_plus package, and it works well on Android for scanning BLE devices in both foreground and background modes. However, on iOS, it only works in the foreground and does not function in the background.
This package Return Empty List and also tried CoreLocation Native flow as well, but isn't work.
I’ve tried multiple approaches, but none of them have worked so far.
Could you please help me find a solution for this?
Yes, I have added this for UIBackgroundModes. <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>     <array>         <string>bluetooth-central</string>      <string>fetch</string>      <string>location</string>       <string>remote-notification</string>     </array> 
I also added this content to the Info.plist file. <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>     <string>This app requires Bluetooth to scan for devices.</string>     <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>     <string>This app uses Bluetooth to communicate with nearby devices.</string>     <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>     <string>App needs location permission</string>     <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>     <string>App needs location permission</string>     <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>     <string>""</string> 

Did you add the correct UIBackgroundModes in Info.plist? Also, what are you scanning for? According to this post, "your app must explicitly scan for one or more services"

@robertklep Yes, I have added this for UIBackgroundModes.
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>     <array>      <string>bluetooth-central</string>      <string>fetch</string>      <string>location</string>      <string>remote-notification</string>     </array>

I also added this content to the Info.plist file.
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>     <string>This app requires Bluetooth to scan for devices.</string>     <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>     <string>This app uses Bluetooth to communicate with nearby devices.</string>     <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>     <string>App needs location permission</string>     <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>     <string>App needs location permission</string>     <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>     <string>""</string> 

Please add all that to your question.
